# What is resource of mining rewards

Tags: transaction-fees, mining-theory, mining-reward, hashpower, proof-of-work

How the coins must be paid miners for mining process is provided? One of resources may be **transactions fee**. Is there any other resources for proving reward of miners?

Answer (score 2):

Miners receive a block subsidy and any transaction fees in the block.

The subsidy started at 50BTC and halves every 210,000 blocks. See [Mining Reward](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining#Reward). These are newly minted coins the network accepts as valid coins based on consensus rules above.

Comment: Thank you, (1) what does **halve** meaning here? and (2) can we say that "In Bitcoin, it is crucial to incentivize miners by **monetary** reward, because mining process has **significant monetary cost** (energy/electricity cost)." ? otherwise, mining process is not **affordable** for miners ? is it correct? Thanks

Comment: (1) halve means it will drop by a factor of 2. Blocks 0-209,999 = 50 BTC, 210,000-419,999 = 25 BTC, etc.
(2) sort of, it provides a reward for mining so there is incentive to mine. it also creates predictable minting of a fixed supply of coins

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get a good idea about mining by watching this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUud-Pz8fE4&t=7s also for pow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-W3uM2u_24&t=200s

Comment: Are you affiliated with the channel in any way? If so, you must disclose your affiliation, it will be considered spam otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Miners gets their rewards for maintaining the work and security of the network. Each time they successfully form a block, they receive a fixed amount of crypto currency. That’s how Blockchain generates its own money.

Comment: I know, but how do produce these coins? What is the resource?  For example, transactions fee?